# How to decrease/increase a counter in an excel column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which has below ids , starting from `L_Char_18`:

[image]

I want IDs to start from `L_Char_16` and ending at `L_Char_50`. So in each row ID should decrease by 2. Is it possible to do it with a function/formula in Excel  ? I don't want to change IDs in each row manually.

Comment: How do drag it down exactly? This IDs are in column A by the way.

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani If you type in the first 3 entries manually ("L_Char_16" / "L_Char_18" / "L_Char_20"), select all 3 cells, and then click-and-drag on the small square in the bottom right of the selection, Excel will automatically pattern-match the data

Comment: yes.  for every new jump,I wrote first entry and then I clicked and dragged

Answer (score 0):

Here are two formula-based approach but please note it is based on the assumption that **there is always 2-digit numerical characters at the end of each string**.

```
=REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2)-1,2,--RIGHT(A2,2)-2)
```

or

```
=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)&(--RIGHT(A2,2)-2)
```

[image: Solutions]

Familiarize yourself with **LEFT**, **RIGHT**, **LEN** and **REPLACE** functions will help. Cheers :)